# Neo4j - How to use results of a cypher query in another query using neo4j-driver in python

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I am building a web-application using flask and Neo4j as graph database. I am using official neo4j-driver for python.
Is there a way I can use the results (nodes) returned from a cypher query through a session transaction in another session as nodes. 
Basically, I wanna do something which is equal to a WITH statement but goes across sessions. For example -

```
CALL spatial.withinDistance('geomap', {latitude:18.5, longitude:73.5}, 
50) YIELD node
WITH node.event_id AS eventID
MATCH (a:Topic{topic_id:7})<-[b:TOPIC_RELATION]-(c:Event)
WHERE c.event_id in eventID
RETURN c
```

I want to be able to extract the result in the first statement and then use it in another session to match it with event_id.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "other session" and how you will be us the nodes in this next session? You could use collect(a) as ASet and then use this downstream.  But it's hard to suggest more without further detail.

Comment: Just create an array of `event_id` and pass it to the next query.  You can't pass a node to an other query ... so you need to find it by its id.